# Table without ID's in other Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

In my SQL Server 2008 I've got two tables.

1. Table: All kinds of Users with unique ID's
2. Table: Blacklisted Users with ID's

Now I'd like to get all Users that are not on the blacklist.
Just doesn't work like I want it to

```
SELECT A.ID, B.ID FROM Users AS A INNER JOIN Blacklist AS B ON
A.ID != B.ID
```

Can someone help?

Comment: SELECT A.*
    FROM Users A
    Where A.ID NOT IN (Select Id From Blacklist )


Works. Thanks huMpty DuMty

Comment: For your information: we don't usually put comment like this! If you got correct answer you can accept it by clicking check mark which is next to the answer. If any of the answer help you solve the problem, you up vote the answer (I know you don't have enough reputation to vote yet but keep in mind for future) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect it to not to be in Blacklist, you won't have any data to select from blacklist in select statement

```
   SELECT A.*
    FROM Users A
    Where A.ID NOT IN (Select Id From Blacklist )
```

If you wish, read more about [Subqueries with NOT IN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189062%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is an anti-join, something like this:

```
SELECT A.ID, B.ID FROM Users AS A LEFT JOIN Blacklist AS B ON
A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.ID IS NULL
```

That is, we perform the join, and then in the `WHERE` clause we apply a filter which eliminates rows where the join was successful.

Your original query doesn't work (assuming that there is more than one row in `Blacklist` and that they have different `ID` values) because, for *any* `ID` value in `A`, we can find *a* row in `B` which doesn't match it - even if there's *also* a row which does match it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
From Users 
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID From BlackListedUsers)
```

That should select all that are not in the blacklist table.